# Simulation of a dynamic search and matching model

Tags: dynamic-programming, search-and-matching, model, matlab, labour

I want to simulate a search and matching model very close to the canonical model developed by Pissarides. I am interested in representing the trajectory of the unemployment rate when the unemployment insurance parameters are changed by the government.

I have never done numerical simulations of general equilibrium models before so I don't really know where and how to start. I am coding in Matlab, and I began by calculating the steady-state equilibrium values of the endogenous parameters but I would also like to model their dynamic behavior, in particular the transition to a new steady-state. Do you know how I can do that ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Not yet search and matching, but [QuantEcon](https://python.quantecon.org/mccall_model.html#) may be a useful start to get into the computation.